# В чем заключается ошибка?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Есть код:

```
using System;

namespace Acces_control
{
    public class Worker : Human
    {
        public int work_experience {
            get { return work_experience; }
            set {
                if ((value <= 90) && (value >= 0)) {
                    work_experience = value;
                } else {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
        }

        public string ZoneOfWork {
            get { return ZoneOfWork; }
            set { ZoneOfWork = value; }
        }

        public Worker()
        {
            work_experience = 0;
            ZoneOfWork = "NA";
        }
    }
}
```

ЗЫ: в классе Human содержится просто пара переменных типа Name и LastName
Когда изменяю переменную work_experience:

```
var worker = new Worker();
worker.work_experience = 10;
```

получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Stack overflow: IP: 0x4018a914, fault addr: 0x7ffefce96ff0
Stacktrace:
  at Acces_control.Worker.set_work_experience (int) [0x00013] in /home/vasya/Programming/C#/Tests/Classes/Acces_control/Worker.cs:11
  <...>
  at Acces_control.Worker..ctor () [0x00009] in /home/vasya/Programming/C#/Tests/Classes/Acces_control/Worker.cs:25
  at Acces_control.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x00001] in /home/vasya/Programming/C#/Tests/Classes/Acces_control/Program.cs:9
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00058, 0xffffffff>

Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: При инициализации класса Worker происходит инициализация свойства work_experience = 0;. т.к. условие (value <= 90) && (value >= 0) не выполняется генерируется исключение throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

Comment: @NMD, (0 <= 90) && (0 >= 0) не выполняется?..

Comment: ох, точно. @Alekcvp вы правы. тогда не понятно что

Comment: Alekcvp прав: происходит рекурсивное обращение к свойству. Нужно ввести поле для хранения и его устанавливать в сеттере свойства.

Answer (score 3):

Stack overflow чаще всего означает бесконечную рекурсию. Вы в get/set этого свойства обращаетесь к нему же, пытаясь получить/изменить его значение, и, соответственно, получаете бесконечную рекурсию. Посмотрите как сделано [вот здесь (см.ниже)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w86s7x04.aspx) - там используется отдельная переменная для хранения значения свойства:

```
public class Date
{
    private int month = 7;  // тут хранится значение свойства

    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            return month;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value > 0) && (value < 13))
            {
                month = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло. Всё тот - же Stack Overflow.

Comment: Не может быть нужно добавить переменную private int _work_experience = 0;
и в геттере брать из нее значение, а в сеттере заносить в нее значение. все же расписал @Alekcvp

Comment: @NMD незнаю как, но это возможно.

Comment: @cheloca покажите код, чтобы вам могли помочь